# Strategy to create BBST when we know that most of the inserts are in order?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have a situation where I need a balanced binary search tree. I have used AVL tree, but it needs lots of rotations to create balance height while inserting. I have observed that most of inputs are already in order. For ex: 8 9 10 11 12 13 2 14 15 16 17 4 18 19 20 etc... Is there is a better strategy of creating a BBST when we know that most of inputs are already in order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), which has good performance on already sorted or nearly sorted arrays (it has performance `O(n + d)`, where `d` is the number of inversions). Of course, you wouldn't want to do this if the array is not sorted at all, in which case it will take `O(n2)`, as opposed to other sorting algorithms which take `O(n log n)`.

After running this, you could [construct the BST in `O(n)`](http://leetcode.com/2010/11/convert-sorted-array-into-balanced.html):

> If you would have to choose an array element to be the root of a balanced BST, which element would you pick? The root of a balanced BST should be the middle element from the sorted array.
>
> You would pick the middle element from the sorted array in each iteration. You then create a node in the tree initialized with this element. After the element is chosen, what is left? Could you identify the sub-problems within the problem?
>
> There are two arrays left — The one on its left and the one on its right. These two arrays are the sub-problems of the original problem, since both of them are sorted. Furthermore, they are subtrees of the current node’s left and right child.

Comment: Timsort also makes good use of ascending or descending runs in the input array and has worst case `O(n log n)` complexity

Answer (score 2):

Sort the inputs using insertion sort; this is normally an O(n^2) algorithm, but is O(n) if the input is nearly sorted. Then put the middle element of the input at the root of the tree, recursively put the middle element of the left half of the input at the root of the root's left sub-tree and the middle element of the right half of the input at the root of the root's right sub-tree, and so on until the entire input is in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

suppose arr is nearly sorted array then you can do following to get good balanced tree from it:-

```
make_tree(BST,arr,high,low) {

  if(high>=low) {

      mid = (high+low)/2;
      BST.insert(arr[mid]);
      make_tree(BST,arr,mid-1,low);
      make_tree(BST,arr,high,mid+1);
  }

}

make_tree(BST,arr,N-1,0);
```

**Explanation:-** As array is almost sorted we are dividing it into equal halves the average time complexity of insert is `O(logN)` and hence time complexity is `O(nlogn)`